# Change \includegraphics to a TikZ \pic in \pgfplotstabletypeset

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, tikz-pic

I would like to change the content of my pgf table column "Image" from using an included graphic to a predefined TikZ `\pic` based on the information in column "Type". The `\pic` should be centered horizontally and vertically inside of the `table`.

**Here is my working MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{mwe}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Image,       ID,    Description,  Type,        X-Pos,   Y-Pos,   rotation
powerSupply, A1F5F, PowerSupply1, PowerSupply, 3590,    2000,    270 
powerSupply, 7ZF3I, PowerSupply2, PowerSupply, 3590,    2500,    270
powerSupply, O7PYQ, PowerSupply3, PowerSupply, 4250,    6070,    180
powerSupply, A7HAZ, Switch1,      singleSwitch,5700,    6070,    180
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\CSVDataRows{\pgfplotsretval-1} 

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
font=\ttfamily,%
col sep=comma,%
columns={Image, ID, Description, Type, X-Pos, Y-Pos},%
columns/Image/.style={%
column name=Image,%
assign cell content/.code={%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{example-image}}}  %==> This should be changed to add a TikZ \pic depending on the type column!
},%
columns/ID/.style={%
column name=ID,%
string type%
},%
columns/Description/.style={%
column name=Description,%
string type%
},%
columns/Type/.style={%
column name=Type,%
string type%
},%
columns/X-Pos/.style={%
column name=X-Pos%
},%
columns/Y-Pos/.style={%
column name=Y-Pos,%
column type/.add={}{|}%
},%
column type/.add={|}{},%
after row={\hline},%
every head row/.style={before row=\hline},
]{\csvdata}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**For Example we could use these two mini TikZ**

```
%PowerOutlet
\tikzset{
 pics/stove/.style={
  code={
   \begin{scope}[scale=\resultImageScale]
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric](0,0)--(0,1);
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric](-1,1)--(1,1);
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric,line cap=round](-1,2) arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,radius=1] node[midway,above,sloped,font=\bfseries] {\scalebox{\scaleRatio}{1}};
  \end{scope}
  }
 }
}

%Button
\tikzset{
 pics/stove/.style={
  code={
   \begin{scope}[scale=\resultImageScale]
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric](0,0) circle[radius=1];
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric](0,0) circle[radius=0.6];
   \end{scope}
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Pleas add a MWE - see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: You should replace `\cincludegraphics[scale=0.07]{../Images/ElectricComponents/##1.png}}` (why `\cincludegraphics` by the way?) to something like `\tikz{ \pic {button}; }`. Your follow-up question can only be answered if you provide a full MWE, because currently there are parts in the code of which the defintion is unclear.

Comment: Please take the burden to rework your code snippets into something we can work with, e.g. using https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . Thank you

Comment: Sorry, all of you are completely right! I edited my whole question, added a working MWE which can be compiled with [overleaf](https://de.overleaf.com/project/5df7826d96fa490001851663) and added two `\pic`'s for the answer example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just replace `\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{example-image}` in your code by `\tikz{ \pic{<pic name>}; }`.

The second part in the key `pics/stove/.style` (that is `stove`) is the name of the pic. So, if you define different pics, you should name them differently. If you define a pic named `stove` this way, you can call it via  `\pic{stove};` in a `tikzpicture`.

Note that there are some commands in the defintions of the pics you show, that are not defined, so I needed to define them in the below MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{mwe}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\def\resultImageScale{1}
\def\resultLineScaleMetric{0.4pt}
\def\scaleRatio{1}

%PowerOutlet
\tikzset{
 pics/PowerOutlet/.style={
  code={
   \begin{scope}[scale=\resultImageScale]
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric](0,0)--(0,1);
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric](-1,1)--(1,1);
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric,line cap=round](-1,2) arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,radius=1] node[midway,above,sloped,font=\bfseries] {\scalebox{\scaleRatio}{1}};
  \end{scope}
  }
 }
}

%Button
\tikzset{
 pics/button/.style={
  code={
   \begin{scope}[scale=\resultImageScale]
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric](0,0) circle[radius=1];
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric](0,0) circle[radius=0.6];
   \end{scope}
  }
 }
}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Image,       ID,    Description,  Type,        X-Pos,   Y-Pos,   rotation
PowerOutlet, A1F5F, PowerSupply1, PowerSupply, 3590,    2000,    270 
PowerOutlet, 7ZF3I, PowerSupply2, PowerSupply, 3590,    2500,    270
button,      O7PYQ, PowerSupply3, PowerSupply, 4250,    6070,    180
button,      A7HAZ, Switch1,      singleSwitch,5700,    6070,    180
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\CSVDataRows{\pgfplotsretval-1} 

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
font=\ttfamily,%
col sep=comma,%
columns={Image, ID, Description, Type, X-Pos, Y-Pos},%
columns/Image/.style={%
column name=Image,%
assign cell content/.code={%
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\tikz{\pic{##1};}}
}
},%
columns/ID/.style={%
column name=ID,%
string type%
},%
columns/Description/.style={%
column name=Description,%
string type%
},%
columns/Type/.style={%
column name=Type,%
string type%
},%
columns/X-Pos/.style={%
column name=X-Pos%
},%
columns/Y-Pos/.style={%
column name=Y-Pos,%
column type/.add={}{|}%
},%
column type/.add={|}{},%
after row={\hline},%
every head row/.style={before row=\hline},
]{\csvdata}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If the `Type` in your table data is identical to the name of the relevant `\pic` (that is, the `Image` and the `Type` columns are identical copies), you can delete the `Image` column from your table and create this column as copy of the `Type` column automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\def\resultImageScale{1}
\def\resultLineScaleMetric{0.4pt}
\def\scaleRatio{1}

%PowerOutlet
\tikzset{
 pics/PowerSupply/.style={
  code={
   \begin{scope}[scale=\resultImageScale]
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric](0,0)--(0,1);
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric](-1,1)--(1,1);
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric,line cap=round](-1,2) arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,radius=1] node[midway,above,sloped,font=\bfseries] {\scalebox{\scaleRatio}{1}};
  \end{scope}
  }
 }
}

%Button
\tikzset{
 pics/singleSwitch/.style={
  code={
   \begin{scope}[scale=\resultImageScale]
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric](0,0) circle[radius=1];
     \draw[red,line width=\resultLineScaleMetric](0,0) circle[radius=0.6];
   \end{scope}
  }
 }
}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
ID,    Description,  Type,        X-Pos,   Y-Pos,   rotation
A1F5F, PowerSupply1, PowerSupply, 3590,    2000,    270 
7ZF3I, PowerSupply2, PowerSupply, 3590,    2500,    270
O7PYQ, PowerSupply3, PowerSupply, 4250,    6070,    180
A7HAZ, Switch1,      singleSwitch,5700,    6070,    180
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\CSVDataRows{\pgfplotsretval-1} 

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/copy={Type}
]{Image}{\csvdata}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    font=\ttfamily,%
    col sep=comma,%
    columns={Image, ID, Description, Type, X-Pos, Y-Pos},%
    columns/Image/.style={
        column name=Image,%
        assign cell content/.code={%
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\tikz{\pic{##1};}}
        }
    },
    columns/ID/.style={%
        column name=ID,%
        string type%
    },%
    columns/Description/.style={%
        column name=Description,%
        string type%
    },%
    columns/Type/.style={%
        column name=Type,%
        string type%
    },%
    columns/X-Pos/.style={%
        column name=X-Pos%
    },%
    columns/Y-Pos/.style={%
        column name=Y-Pos,%
        column type/.add={}{|}%
    },%
    column type/.add={|}{},%
    after row={\hline},%
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline},
]{\csvdata}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you center the `\pic`'s vertically? And can we remove the column `Image` in raw data and still show it in the result table? The `\pic` can be defined by the `column` type.

Comment: I got the first topic by myself :) With `\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\tikz{\pic[scale=0.003]{##1};` the `\pic` is beautiful centered! But could you maybe have a look on the second part of my question? I don't get it how to create such an `image`column in my result table, without having this column also in the `input.csv`. This information could be removed in the input data, because the type information which is used to determine the correct `\pic` is already given in the `Type` column...

Comment: @PascalS I don't know exactly what you mean. Currently, the `image` column contains just the name of the `\pic{<name>}`. But you mean that you want to use the contents from the `type` column in two columns in the typset table?

Comment: The point is, that there are two columns which have exactly the same content. This is, because the `type` is automatically also the `\pic`'s name. Therefore one column is redundant. So I just search for a way to choose the '\pic''s name from the `type` column and in the best case I also want to remove the `Image` column from my raw data. Because in my raw I don't need the `image` column information, when it is already stored in the `type` column. The reason behind is, that there will be a lot of columns and the more I can reduce, the better I can oversee :)

Comment: @PascalS You can automatically make copies from existing columns. See the last edit of my answer.

Comment: Great, that works!

Comment: Now I‘m very close to my final solution. I just need to be able to dynamically adapt the amount of tables and pictures. Could you have a look at this? [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/711939/create-more-than-one-table-tikz-picture-out-of-a-single-pgfplot-data-base](Qestion)